# Prevent SliverAppBar title from wrapping while it shrinks in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Flutter app that uses a SliverAppBar in a CustomScrollView. The SliverAppBar's title is really long, so as the AppBar compresses on scrolling, the title starts to wrap several times.

I would like to prevent this behavior without using an overflow.
Note that the title can just "slide out", without being pinned at the top.

This allows for some possibilities, like:

- shrinking the title, but not changing it's wrapping
- keeping the title the same size, preventing it from wrapping at all

GIF:

[image: GIF demonstration]

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 300,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Image.network(
                    'https://picsum.photos/500?grayscale&blur=2',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  title: Text(
                      'This is a very long title that will wrap several times while it shrinks'),
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Text(
                  '\nScrollable body:\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `SizedBox` wrapped inside a `FittedBox`:

```
title: FittedBox(
  child: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        'This is a very long title that will wrap several times while it shrinks',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Result:

[image: res]

Comment: In addition for the above answer, for those who want to avoid shrinking altogether: set the `toolbarHeight` property of `SliverAppBar` to something bigger, eg. `110`.
This way the title will fade out before it has a chance to start shrinking.